# How to create new cells in excel based upon the contents of another cell

Tags: excel

I'm attempting to create a database of barcode values to print onto labels, and to do so I need a list of all the values to print. If I have Cell A1 as *value* and Cell A2 as *numbers of item*, say 4, is there a way to then get four rows which contain *value*?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably show sample data with the expected output. You also need to show what you have tried!

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1) > $A$2,"",$A$1)
```

and copy  downward:

[image]